# Is there a word for "fat gained from holiday eating"?

Tags: single-word-request

I'm looking for a word (noun) that means "fat gained by extra eating during the holidays".

There's a similar word "Kummerspeck" for "fat from emotional eating".

Example:

> Ich habe viel gegessen für das neue Jahr. Ich habe 1 kg ___ zugenommen.

(I ate a lot for New Year. I gained 1 kg of "fat from holiday eating".)

Comment: _Feiertagsplauze_ :D

Comment: Seriously, I don't think there's some single word other than used colloquially.

Answer (score 4):

You may say "***Urlaubsspeck***", just google it, there are hundreds of hits.

Comment: Auch Weihnachtsspeck.

Comment: Oder eben _Feiertagsplauze_ :D

Comment: Mir ist es unter dem Begriff *Feiertagsspeck* bekannt. - Die *Plauze* ist ja eher der Körperteil, der dadurch ungewollt angewachsen ist, nicht das Fett an sich.

Comment: Die Bedeutungen sind da nicht vollständig deckungsgleich, Urlaub hat man ja nicht nur an Weihnachten, aber da wird besonders viel gegessen und sich wenig bewegt. '_Plauze_' ist vermutlich regional, bei uns (Ruhr) sagt man auch '_Wampe_'. Da kommt's auch drauf an, wo die Kalorienbomben abgelagert werden, für manche sind 'Hüftgold' und 'Rettungsringe' ein größeres Problem als der Schmerbauch.

Comment: Feiertagspfunde, Urlaubspfunde wird sicher auch verstanden, dann muss man aber umrechnen; statt "1 kg ~" wären es dann "2 Feiertagspfunde" (500 g = 1 Pfund = 0,5 kg). Gehört/gelesen habe ich das aber noch nicht, zumindest nicht mit "Feiertag".

Answer (score 2):

As you are obviously refering to the traditional winter holiday season (Christmas, New Year's Eve), you may use

> Winterspeck

Unless you are from Australia.

Answer (score 1):

There are some suggestions in other answers and comments that are used colloquially. 
You can also just make one up.

How about

> Weihnachtswampe?

Comment: *Weihnachtswampe* is a nice one (as long as the fat is located in the belly region). But what do you mean by "official" word?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Hm. Good question. I'll just delete that. Tnx for the note. ;)